# awk: splitting with a regex

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to parse lines with fields separated by "|" and space padding. I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
$ echo "1 a  | 2 b  |  3 c " | awk -F' *| *' '{ print "-->" $2 "<--" }'
```

However, what I get is

```
-->a<--
```

instead of the expected

```
-->2 b<--
```

I'm using GNU Awk 4.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `' *| *'`, `awk`interprets it as `space` **OR** `space`. Hence the output you get is correct one. If you need to have `|` as a delimiter, just escape it.

```
$ echo "1 a  | 2 b  |  3 c " | awk -F' *\\| *' '{ print "-->" $2 "<--" }'
-->2 b<--
```

Notice that you have to escape it twice, since in `awk`, `\|` is considered `|` as well which will again get interpreted as logical **OR**.

Because of this, it is very popular to escape such special characters in character class `[]`.

```
$ echo "1 a  | 2 b  |  3 c " | awk -F' *[|] *' '{ print "-->" $2 "<--" }'
-->2 b<--
```

Comment: Depending on your shell, you might find you need 3 backslashes: `-F ' *\\\| *'` -- good advice to go with a character class.

Comment: Ouch. I was so focussed on matching the "|" that I didn't realize that it matches alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "1 a | 2 b | 3 c " | awk -F '|' '{print $2}' | tr -d ' '
```

produces "2 b" for me

Comment: No it do not give "2 b", it give ` 2 b `, space before and after and that is what OP did not like.

Comment: Fixed it. No escape sequence needed.